# How to Bind an Observablecollection to a GridView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I am working on an App that selects Images and adds them to an Observablecollection. I want to show this collection in Xaml. There is no clear understandable answer that I have found so far.

in the MainPage:

```
public ObservableCollection<TimerWallpaper> timerWallpapers = new ObservableCollection<TimerWallpaper>();
```

And then the code for its class is this:

```
public class TimerWallpaper
{
    public string timerFileName;
    public BitmapImage timerImgSource;
    public string timerTime;
    public TimerWallpaper(string name, BitmapImage imgSource, int hours, int mins)
    {
        this.timerFileName = name;
        this.timerImgSource = imgSource;
        this.timerTime = hours.ToString() + " : " + mins.ToString();
    }
}
```

Till this point it seems as the code is working.. the obstacle is with this code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="x:Bind timerWallpapers">
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TimerWallpaper">
      <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="x:Bind timerImgSource"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind timerFileName}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind timerTime}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I keep getting "Invalid Value" for the elements of the data templet.
What are the requirements to bind the GridView to the collection?
What is the correct format to do so?

Answer (score 2):

OK, there are a number of problems with your code. First off, you should bind to properties, not fields, so your `MainPage.cs` should look something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<TimerWallpaper> TimerWallpapers { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TimerWallpapers = new ObservableCollection<TimerWallpaper>();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

and your `TimerWallpaper` like this:

```
public class TimerWallpaper
{
    public string TimerFileName { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage TimerImgSource { get; set; }
    public string TimerTime { get; set; }

    public TimerWallpaper(string name, BitmapImage imgSource, int hours, int mins)
    {
        this.TimerFileName = name;
        this.TimerImgSource = imgSource;
        this.TimerTime = hours.ToString() + " : " + mins.ToString();
    }
}
```

(Or use private set if you want to)

Next, your binding syntax is wrong on a couple of lines where you forgot to enclose it in curly braces, and lastly, the `DataTemplate` can only have a single child, so you need to wrap your UI elements in a layout, e.g. a `StackPanel`, like so:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind TimerWallpapers}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TimerWallpaper">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{x:Bind TimerImgSource}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TimerFileName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TimerTime}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```